# How to Automatically Convert Markdown (.md) to HTML and Render it in a Specific <div> Element using Node.js and markdown-it?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm, markdown

I'm working on a project where my customer wants to be able to type Markdown (MD) content in a .md file and have it automatically converted to HTML. The generated HTML should then be displayed in a specific  element within an HTML file.

I've set up a Node.js project and installed the necessary packages (markdown-it and fs). Here's the code I'm using in my convert.js file:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const markdownIt = require('markdown-it');

const mdContent = fs.readFileSync('ru/input.md', 'utf-8');

const htmlContent = markdownIt.render(mdContent);

const divElement = document.querySelector('.vlog');
divElement.innerHTML = htmlContent;
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="vlog">

    </div>
</main>
```

However, when I type anything in the .md file, it doesn't seem to automatically convert the content. I've attached a screenshot of my project structure for reference.

[image]

What could be causing this issue, and how can I make it work as intended? Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any output on your app (console errors, logs, warnings... ?)

This can help to solve your problem

Comment: ^^ there is actually error `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:5500/ru/scripts/convert.js:1` but i dont really know why, cuz i installed `fs`

Comment: `require` can be used only in node.js environment but it seems you are on frontend environment.
You need to use `<script>` with cdn or `import`.
Another problem is `fs` can only be used in server environment (node.js for exemple).

So either you need to apply markdown transformation on server side, or use another method on frontend.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `require` and `fs` because it's server side only and you're on frontend side. You have to use specific method compatible with frontend.

### keep files - Fetch

if you want to keep files, you can use fetch, like this :

```js
fetch('../ru/input.md') // Adjust it with your routes
  .then(response => {
    // Check if response is ok
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
    }
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(mdContent => {
    // Use markdown-it to convert your HTML
    const markdownIt = window.markdownit();
    const htmlContent = markdownIt.render(mdContent);

    const divElement = document.querySelector('.vlog');
    divElement.innerHTML = htmlContent;
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.error('Error fetching Markdown file:', e);
  });
```